# How to avoid to add the target folder into a GIT commit?

Tags: git, version-control, git-commit, git-push, git-add

I am not so into GIT and I have a doubt.

I have a project that is composed by these folders and file:

```
$ ls
bin/  lock.lck  pom.xml  src/  target/
```

I know that doing:

```
git add .
```

I am adding all the files in my staging area, so if then I commit and push on my remote repository I will put on this repository also the **target** folder.

I want to avoid this situation.

How can I avoid to add, commit and push the **terget** folder?

Comment: As everyone else has mentioned, using [.gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Answer (score 4):

Move to root directory of the project in parallel to `.git` folder, create [`.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) file and copy the below content:

```
target/
```

Answer (score 1):

add an item to .gitignore so git doesn't pay attention to it (if files haven't been added to previous revisions).

Comment: And what is the correct location of this .gitignore file?

Answer (score 0):

Add the path to your file which you would like to ignore to your .gitignore file.

Example:

```
*.class
target
.classpath
.settings
```

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: where have I to put this .gitignore file? In the main folder of my project? and what should contains? Something like terget/ ? or what?

Comment: .gitignore can be placed at the root of the project but I also think that it can be  placed in other directories within the project (in which case each works on the directory and subdirectories where it's set up). And you put there lines with patterns you want git to not track:

for example:
```
*.class
*.log
target
```

Comment: Ok, but I have to specify to use this .gitignore settings when I do git add . or is it automatic?

Comment: if you add stuff into .gitignore after you have added the files, it does not work. It's just a plain text file. Add the items to the .gitignore and then try adding. git should skip those items you have set up in .gitignore

Comment: @Ershany I edited your answer without noticing it was _not_ my answer. I'll leave it because it can be seen as an expansion, I think. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t want to add `target` folder into commit, you should add the folder into `.gitignore`. The `.gitignore` file usually created in the root path of a git repo. You can use below ways to created `.gitignore` file, and ignore `target` folder:

```
touch .gitignore
echo target >> .gitignore
# If you committed files and subfolders of target in git, use below commits
git rm 1/* --cached -r
git commit -m 'remove target in version control'
```

Now the `target` folder is totally ignored by git, and it won’t be committed in git.